# Best way to rotate Apache log files

Tags: apache, logging, webserver, apache2, apache2.4

I've got an Apache server that has one access log file that is topping 600MB.  This makes it really hard to search the file or parse it.
What software or modules for Apache are available that will make a daily copy of my access file to make it more manageable?

Comment: Lucky you - the one I'm facing is 2.4 GIGABYTES :(

Comment: You could indicate whether you are really looking for an Apache module, or something that depends on the employed OS, such as logrotate or cron (already mentioned in the answers). That could help in replying to this - in my opinion - simple question.

Comment: 14GB here! Just over one year of entries.

Comment: I don't care about the logs and only want them to not grow unlimited:  on WIN i used this to have max 7x15 mb logs.   CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l logs/access.%A.log 15M" common

Comment: scratch that, according to Bug 51081 https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51081  rotatelogs will not overwrite

Comment: 23 GB here, on an old server... this should be a built-in feature

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Have you looked at [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) - this is probably the simplest, most widely available and well understood method of achieving this.  It is highly configurable and will probably do 90% of what you need.

Comment: A usage example like Brian's answer would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The downside to `logrotate` is that the logfile will continue to get written to the old filename until the process restarts.

Answer (score 28):

I'm a big fan of [Cronolog](https://github.com/fordmason/cronolog).  Just install and pipe your logs through it.  For daily log rotation, something like this would work:

```
ErrorLog  "|/usr/bin/cronolog /path/to/logs/%Y-%m-%d/error.log"
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /path/to/logs/%Y-%m-%d/access.log" combined
```

Pretty handy, and once installed, easier (in my experience) than logrotate.

Comment: when I used cronolog i encountered some issues when the log file reached 2GB of data. At that point there was no more logging and apache stalled until i removed/renamed the file. Since then I'm using logrotate and all is fine :)

Answer (score 13):

The actual command for Windows, which is quite difficult to find online is:

```
CustomLog '|" "*Apache-Path/bin/rotatelogs.exe" 
    "**Apache-Path*/logs/backup/internet_access_%d-%m-%y.log" 86400' combined
```

Where the "internet_access" bit is the name you choose for your files, the 86400 is the number of seconds in one day.  You need to change the Apache-Path to the relevant directory you've installed Apache to.

Comment: Instead of dealing with trying to wrap quotes around the paths, I ended up shortening them, such as "c:/Progra~1/..."  Also, it took awhile, but I eventually realized that I needed forward slashes in the paths.

Comment: Don't use backslashes in the path, it won't work! Alternatively, you can use [mod_log_rotate](http://www.sitebuddy.com/mod_log_rotate). Using this mod prevents also cmd.exe issues under Windows.

Comment: I did had some issues in Apache2.4 (Windows 8) for implementing log rotation. But fixed as below.

In httpd.conf file add the following line
ServerRoot "c:/Apache24" # Apache installation path

#CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs logs/access.log.%Y-%m-%d 86400" common
# This above does not work, but when added .exe, it worked.

CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/access.log.%Y-%m-%d 86400" common

Comment: Note that the `-n 4` "circular logs" option might not work as expected unless you add the `-L basename` option.

Comment: @alimack Can you give exact command for configuration rotatelog because am getting  `unable to open log error`  while i trying to start apache server.

Comment: Unable to open file sounds like permissions - create a blank file with the correct name and check the write permissions.

Comment: This is good enough to me
         `ErrorLog '| "bin/rotatelogs.exe" "logs/error_%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.log" 10M'`

Answer (score 11):

## logrotate

`logrotate` is probably the best solution. Use the file `/etc/logrotate.conf` to change the settings for all your logs. You van change `weekly` to `daily` so the logs are rotated every day. Also, you might want to add `compress` so the archives are compressed. If you don't care about the old logs, you can set rotate `rotate 4` to something lower.

Comment: I'm intrigued - what are the differences between this and the apache-supplied 'rotatelogs'? And why doesn't the apache manual mention logrotate (yet it does refer to cronolog)?

Comment: Just an assumption: this could be because logrotate is not available on all system Apache is running. I have only used it on Linux installations, where it is used to rollover all of the system logs, and of course Apache's log files.

Answer (score 3):

CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs /var/logs/logfile 5M" common

This configuration will rotate the logfile whenever it reaches a size of 5 megabytes.

```
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs /var/logs/errorlog.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M"
```

This Would Be Best Way to Redirect Apache logs. No need to compile mod with httpd.

Comment: Is there some rotatelogs option to delete old files or to overwrite them?

Comment: @Tobia did you find a solution to delete old files ?

Comment: Not with date log names, I had to switch to indexed log names (`rotatelogs.exe -n 3  filepath 1M`)

Comment: Using `rotatelogs -t ... 100M`, I find that the logfile is overwritten each time instead of appended to. Is there any way to make `rotatelogs` append to an existing log file?

Answer (score 1):

rotatelog.exe or cronolog.exe on windows os. They are used in pipe command in http.conf
Mod_log_rotate additional module for apache ONLY for access log rotation
Logrotate ONLY for unix os.

Answer (score 0):

I have a module that does this for you without the need for external pipes etc :

http://www.poptart.org/bin/view/Poptart/ModAutorotate

I've tried to add it to the Apache modules collection but that seems to have been broken for a while now.